# Account blocked after receiving multiple +100 reputation rewards

Tags: support, asking-questions, post-ban, banning, association-bonus

Last week I open my Stack Overflow account and I noticed I was rewarded +100 points on my multiples accounts on the network:

[image: Screenshot of reputation chart]

Today I discover that my account on Stack Overflow is blocked:

[image: Screenshot of question ban page]

This is quite strange, because I haven't asked questions on Stack Overflow since a long time.

I have asked a few questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ but they were well received and I still can use my account on Stack Exchange.

Maybe the algorithm is doing something bizarre?

Comment: The reputation bonuses are on the other sites, not on StackOverflow.  AFAIK, they are not relevant to this.

Comment: @Stephen C, if you look at the picture I also had +100 for StackOverflow. As you can see the curve on the graphic is spiking high. Why should my account being blocked **after** I received +100 rewarding points

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this is a matter of [coincidence rather than correlation](https://xkcd.com/552/).

All +100 are [site association bonuses](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation):

> If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions.

On March 2, 2018 [one of your answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47646141/2675154) was upvoted and this made you pass the 200 reputation threshold.
The site association bonus is awarded to all your accounts in the Stack Exchange network.

Regarding your question ban: You usually only notice that you are banned when you try to ask a question. You wrote, that you haven't asked a question on Stack Overflow since a long time. However, you received some [downvotes on some of your questions in December 2017 and January 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4652358/francesco-mantovani?tab=reputation). It might be that you have been banned since then.

FYI: In order to get out of the question ban, [this Q&A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/2675154) is a good start.

Comment: Thank you @honk, don't know if this is the right answer but I will mark it as the right one

Comment: In case that I am wrong and somebody posts the correct answer, you can still move the checkmark over to that answer.